# Mulitple image upload field widget working on custom content nodes but not on user nodes

Tags: media

Using Drupal 7.39 and the [MultiUpload FileField Widget module](https://www.drupal.org/project/multiupload_filefield_widget).

It works fine for articles, and custom content types I create, but it doesn't work for user fields. Even if I take the existing field from article, and add it as a field to user, it doesn't work.

You can select multiple images, and they show as "2 images selected", you click upload, and nothing happens.

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: What module did you use for multiple images upload? Your question is a bit vague and you will need to elaborate a bit more on your setup.

Comment: But it works in Firefox 27, but not in Chrome 38, and in IE 8 nothing...using Twitter Bootstrap 3.X

Comment: So it is then a bug and you can look in the bug report for the module or use another module such as [Media](https://www.drupal.org/project/media)

Comment: Actually, it works with bootstrap 3.0, but not in IE 8, so I guess it's a browser compatibility issue.

Comment: Actually...still not working now...this widget works randomly, like the weather it seems...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was an administration template problem...

It works in bootstrap, but not with 7 theme, but it does with Stark.

I thought that the Drupal 7 theme would be bullet proof, I guess not...

So always best to test various admin themes to see if that is the problem in the future.